# How to programmatically close all segues from one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I programmatically close all segues from one view controller? I want to. close all segues happened by a view controller programmatically without using the storyboard.

Comment: If you have the navigation controller available you can use pop to root view controller method to go to the first.

Comment: I tried it andromedainiative, but on the. second time I do it is sousing all view to because white and remove the data, tables, views and etc.

Comment: @Trutinetko - your question is not clear. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that

- NVC - UINavigationViewController
- VC - UIViewController

**Stacks of views:**

1. NVC - viewControllers -> VC (A) - present -> VC (B) - present -> VC (C)

VC(A).dismiss(animated: true). This will dismiss B and C view controllers

2. NVC - viewControllers -> VC (A) - push -> VC (B) - push -> VC (C)

VC(A).popToViewController(VC (A), animated: true). This will pop B and C view controllers

In both cases the visible view controller is A

Comment: and how can I use this

Comment: @Trutinetko to have more explicit answer you have to include your code in the question